# Anchor tag `download` attribute works in Chrome, but does not work in Firefox. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

By having the `download` attribute, it's supposed to allow direct download of an image (which works in Chrome for my example below).  However, Firefox re-directs the page to the `href` image location (and treats it like a regular link instead).

I think the issue here is that the file is hosted on a different domain (i.e., cross-browser).   I'm not sure how picky Firefox on this, but it works in Chrome though.  I'm only supporting HTML5.  Has anyone ran into something similar?

http://jsfiddle.net/0sck61x3/

```
<a href="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2869/11579908016_c3f94e9998_m.jpg" download='pup'>
 CLICK TO DOWNLOAD 
</a>
```

Comment: OT: What effects provide the attribute 'download'?

Comment: @reporter — It's standard HTML.